# Bash Script to Sort Files into Alphabetical and Numbers Folders (offset the sorting letter to the 8th character)

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

eg file name: 
`9323 - Unix.ext` or `z223 - 50 Cent.ext`

I would like to know how to sort all the files in the current directory into ./A and ./B etc.. and ./Numbers but using the 8th character in the filename as the comparison variable.

'U' and '5' would be the variable to sort by from the example above.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
rename  -n 'if (-f $_) {
   my $c=substr($_,7,1);
   if ($c) {
     mkdir $c unless (-d $c);
     $_="$c/$_" if (-d $c);
   };
}' *.ext
```

This uses the **perl** `rename`  command (also known as `prename` and `file-rename`), **NOT** to be confused with the `rename` command from `util-linux` which has completely different and incompatible command line options.

The script iterates over all files on the command line (or read from STDIN) and if the current file is a regular file (i.e. not a directory, named pipe, socket, etc) then it:

- extracts the 8th character using the `substr()` function into variable $c. substr offsets start from 0, so the `,7,1` refers to the 8th character.
- if `$c` isn't empty (which will happen with short filenames), it:

  - makes the directory `$c` if it doesn't exist.
  - renames the current file into that directory if it is a directory (i.e. doesn't break if `$c` already exists but isn't a directory)

Alternatively, the script could move files into a directory called, e.g., `Misc` if $c is empty:

```
rename -n 'if (-f $_) {
   my $c=substr($_,7,1);
   $c="Misc" unless ($c);
   mkdir $c unless (-d $c);
   $_="$c/$_" if (-d $c);
}' *.ext
```

Note: both examples above use `rename`'s dry-run option (`-n`).  They will only show what the files would be renamed/mv-ed to if you let it.  When you're satisfied that the rename scrript will do what you want, remove the `-n` option (or replace it with `-v` for verbose output).

e.g.

```
$ rename -v  'if (-f $_) { my $c=substr($_,7,1);  $c="Misc" unless ($c) ; mkdir $c unless (-d $c); $_="$c/$_" if (-d $c)}'  *
9323 - Unix.ext renamed as U/9323 - Unix.ext
foo.ext renamed as Misc/foo.ext
z223 - 50 Cent.ext renamed as 5/z223 - 50 Cent.ext
```